# Contact form PHP code not sending 'select' menu

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have the HTML code below for a dropdown menu 'select', and under it is the PHP which is meant to send the selected option. I couldn't find why is it not sending it.

```
<p class="input-block">
    <label for="contact-enquirytype">
        <strong>Drop Menu</strong>
    </label>

    <select for="contact-enquirytype">
        <option type="select" value="Option 1" name="enquirytype" id="contact-enquirytype-1">
            Option 1
        </option>
        <option type="select" value="Option 2" name="enquirytype" id="contact-enquirytype-2">
            Option 2
        </option>

        <option type="select" value="Option 3" name="enquirytype" id="contact-enquirytype-3">
            Option 3
        </option>
    </select>
</p>
```

And the PHP:

```
$select_enquirytype = strip_tags($_POST['enquirytype']);
```

I have other input text and radio which are being sent fine, only the dropdown is not being sent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The `name` attribute must go in the `<select>` tag:

```
<select name="enquirytype">
```

You then must remove it from the `<option>` tags

```
<option value="Option 1" id="contact-enquirytype-1">
```

Comment: The type attribute should be removed from the option elements as well.

Comment: I totally overlooked that. I was too focused on removing the name attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Your select element does not have a name attribute.

Change: `<select for="contact-enquirytype">` to `<select name='enquirytype'>`.
The for attribute is useless here.
Also, your option tags do not need the name attribute, neither do they need a type attribute. The correct way would be:

```
<select name="enquirytype">
    <option value="Option 1" id="contact-enquirytype-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Option 2" id="contact-enquirytype-2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="Option 3" id="contact-enquirytype-3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your select is nowhere near correct.  It should be as follows:

```
<select name="enquirytype">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

And not to be pedantic, but read over [W3C's HTML element guide](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements) if you aren't sure about anything.

Comment: @John Conde: any particular reason why?

Comment: @John Conde: nm, done some research and decided I agree. tnx for the link

Comment: Glad you agree. Makes me happy to have given you the upvote. :)

Comment: Thank for the answer. Though the advice to 'read and get educated' is undue and dull. I will make the decision to read when I want and have the time and the luxury to get educated, otherwise there'd be no point for sites like this. You may want to send the admins a message asking them to close it down so that people 'research the interwebs and get educated'.

Comment: @acidking: You should have left it at 'Thanks for the answer' as the advice to 'read and get educated' is particularly apt in a case like this in which the problem stems from a lack of basic knowledge. 10 minutes spent researching this basic knowledge will save you a huge amount of time in future by making sure you don't need to come on sites like this to ask such basic questions. And as for me, the best advice I ever received on a site like this was 'RTFM!'. Oh, and don't be rude to those who offer you help.

Comment: I happen to not need help if they're planning going to scout me right afterwards. So THANKS FOR NOTHING.